# Loading javascript files in rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a structure in my rails assets directory which is shown below.

```
--javascripts
 -utils // directory
   helper.js
session.js
app.js
application.js
home.js
```

This above is my directory structure in rails. When i load my application i get the below error which i feel is the `JS is not getting loaded properly`.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addMethod' of undefined additional-methods.min.js?body=1:3
Uncaught ReferenceError: Helper is not defined login.js?body=1:22
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'validate' of undefined
```

Below is my application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require vendor
//= require_tree .
```

**Is there anything specific if we have to do for loading files from a specific directory?.** How to load the `Utils` directory and other files in my `application.js`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs:

> Directives are processed top to bottom, but the order in which files
>   are included by require_tree is unspecified. You should not rely on
>   any particular order among those. If you need to ensure some
>   particular JavaScript ends up above some other in the concatenated
>   file, require the prerequisite file first in the manifest.

So if you need something from `Utils` to be defined before anything in, say, `home.js` I'd add `require_directory utils` above the `require_tree .` statement. I suppose this could be what's going wrong with your javascript and throwing the errors you posted.

This is what the docs say about `require_directory`:

> You can also use the require_directory directive which includes all
>   JavaScript files only in the directory specified, without recursion.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anything specific if we have to do for loading files from a
>   specific directory?

The way to do that is to use the [`require_directory` or `require_tree .`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives) directives on the other directory:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
#= require_tree ./utils
```

However, if you're using `require_tree .`, this will basically include all the directories under your `parent` (it's called [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion))

---

As `Nicolay` has mentioned, you're basically looking to include your JS in the correct order. Although I'm unsure as to why you're getting errors for `login.js` and `additional-methods.min.js`

It means your JS is trying to call them, but they are not loaded. This would only cause an error in the likes of precompilation (load order shouldn't be a problem if you're just running in dev)

The answer is to define your manifest as to include the various files when they're needed:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require vendor
//= require bootstrap
```

But more importantly - **how are the functions being called?**